# Invariant Violation: getNodeFromInstance: Invalid argument

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, jestjs

I get `Invariant Violation: getNodeFromInstance: Invalid argument.` when trying to render my component with the `'react-test-renderer'`. When rendering the exact same component with `'react-addons-test-utils'.CreateRenderer().render()`, or when just starting my app, I have no problem. I have read on lot on similar issues, the usual answer is "You have multiple copies of React loaded" or similar, but I tried everything and I couldn't make it work correctly.

```
const result = renderer.create(
    (
      <ContextWrapper>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
          <Navigation />
        </Router>
      </ContextWrapper>
    ),
    document.createElement('div'),
  );
```

My `ContextWrapper` just wraps its children with a muiTheme (see http://www.material-ui.com/ ).

```
class ContextWrapper extends Component {
  getChildContext() {
    return { muiTheme: getMuiTheme() };
  }

  render() {
    return <div>{this.props.children}</div>;
  }
}
```

My `Navigation` contains (all these components are from material-ui) an `AppBar`, and a `Drawer` containing an `AppBar` and 3x custom Component :

```
<Link to={this.props.to}>
  <MenuItem onTouchTap={() => this.handleTouchTap()} >
    {this.props.label}
  </MenuItem>
</Link>
```

Here are my dependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "babel": "^6.23.0",
  "babel-jest": "^19.0.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.22.0",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.23.0",
  "pre-commit": "^1.2.2",
  "deep-freeze": "^0.0.1",
  "eslint": "^3.15.0",
  "eslint-config-airbnb": "^14.1.0",
  "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.2.0",
  "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^4.0.0",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "^6.9.0"
},
"dependencies": {
  "express": "^4.15.2",
  "material-ui": "latest",
  "morgan": "^1.8.1",
  "prop-types": "latest",
  "react": "latest",
  "react-bootstrap": "^0.30.8",
  "react-dom": "latest",
  "react-router-dom": "latest",
  "react-scripts": "^0.9.5",
  "react-tap-event-plugin": "^2.0.1",
  "react-test-renderer": "latest"
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/8324

Comment: Thanks, I have already seen this issue, but I don't use findDOMNode anywhere in my app.

Answer (score 0):

to render components with `react-test-renderer`, you just need a single argument to create component. You should try render your component with create like this example bellow:

```
const result = renderer.create(
    (
      <ContextWrapper>
        <Router history={browserHistory}>
          <Navigation />
        </Router>
      </ContextWrapper>
    )
  );
```

[Take a look here](https://github.com/facebook/react/tree/master/packages/react-test-renderer)

I hope help you!